# How to toggle background-color opacity of a div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using jQuery to open and close a hamburger menu. The class 'no-colour' and 'colour' add or remove a background.

Currently when this runs the background fills suddenly as the class is toggling. I would like it to fade in/out. I've tried 'fadeTo' and 'animate' but I couldn't get them to work as needed.

How to toggle background-color opacity of a div using jQuery?

```
$( '#navButton' ).click(function() {
   $( '.navigation' ).slideToggle( 'slow', function() {
      $( '.no-colour' ).toggleClass( 'colour' );
      $( '.fa-bars' ).toggleClass( 'fa-times' ); 
      // the above is not needed for this example it just swaps the menu icon with a 'x'
   });
});
```

CSS:

```
.colour {
   background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 1);
}

.no-colour {
   background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.1);
}
```

Comment: add transition to the CSS https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yup, transitions should do it:

```
.no-colour {
   background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.1);
   -webkit-transition: background-color 0.7s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: background-color 0.7s ease-out;
   -ms-transition: background-color 0.7s ease-out;
   -o-transition: background-color 0.7s ease-out;
   transition: background-color 0.7s ease-out;
}

.colour {
   background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 1);
}
```

Comment: Typical "vendor-prefixitis". Just because the vendor prefixes exist does not mean they are all supported. For example, `-ms-transition` does not exist.

Comment: @Terry this does not mean the css will fail, is just protecting the `transition` to work on older browsers. And btw, if you use some `less` or `sass` compilers, the `vendor-prefixitis` you call is auto added. So I guess it's not that bad of practice.

Comment: You’re missing the point. Yes the CSS will not fail, but this is bad practice because you’re bloating the code with unnecessary property. While `-webkit-transition` is valid, the Microsoft prefixed counterpart does not even exist. Try autoprefixing `transition` and you’ll find out.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a css `transition` and it will fade in and out for you. Watch it work in the below code snippet.

```js
$( '#navButton' ).click(function() {
   $( '.navigation' ).toggleClass('colour').toggleClass('no-colour')
});
```

```css
.colour {
   background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 1);
  transition: 2s;
}

.no-colour {
   background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.1);
  transition: 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navButton">PRESS</div>
  <div class="navigation no-colour">LKJSDFLSDF</div>
```